# Implementing Book Page sliding animation in winrt

Tags: animation, windows-8, windows-runtime

How to implement Book page slide effect / Animation in winrt. Is anyone tried something similar please share the logic or code. Or else anyone guide me to implement the animation in my application.

NB : I need the visual feedback through mouse move. I created the ordinary sliding animation with next / previous button

Comment: Hi Andrew. y this question On hold? Do you have any answer to the question? It seems most of the user expecting a proper answer to this question including me.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you against doing what you are doing here, @StephanRonald & StezPet...

Comment: In XAML, WinJS or DirectX? The `FlipView` control does a simple slide interaction/animation or do you mean a page curl type of thing? In XAML - that'd be a little bit of work - I haven't seen it on Windows 8 yet, though it could be done with some fairly tricky transforms and clipping or by mixing in a bit of Direct3D integration. The thing is though - page curls are skeuomorphic which would be a bit jarring in the modern Windows world. It's also possibly patented by a company in California.